# Separating hyperplanes of a convex cone

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $W$ be a fixed matrix.
Define

$posW \triangleq \{t |Wy =t , y≥ 0\}$,

It is called the positive hull of $W$. It represents
the set of right-hand sides that can be obtained by a non-negative combination
of the columns of $W$ . The positive hull is easily seen to be a convex cone.

Let $p$ be a point not in the set $posW$. Then, there exist a hyperplane
$H \triangleq \{x |\sigma^Tx =0\}$ that separates $p$ and $posW$.

How can we prove that the number of possible separating hyperplanes (separating $p$  and $posW$)
is finite based on the fact that $posW$ is finitely generated?

Comment: A little drawing in the plane will show that this is not true.

Answer (score 0):

The result is wrong in general. I.e. for $W=0$, $\text{pos }W= \{0\}$. And if $p \neq 0$, there is an infinite number of hyperplanes separating $p$ and $\text{pos } W$.

Comment: Would it be still wrong with the additional assumption that $W\neq 0$? I believe (but have not been able to prove) that the number of separating hyperplanes is equal to rank $W$

Comment: @Patrico,@mathcounterexamples.ne This was adapted from part 1 of Proposition 1 at page 6 of http://www.personal.psu.edu/vvs3/IE597/ie597_lect4.pdf  Could you please check there?

Comment: @Patricio This is also wrong if you take the linear map  defined by $We_1=e_1$ and $We_i=0$ for $i\gt 1$ where $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ stands for the canonical basis.

Answer (score 0):

Take $W=I$, then the positive hull is $Q=\{x | x \ge 0 \}$. Take $p= (-1,...,-1)$ and note that the hyperplanes generated by $H_q = \{ x | q^Tx = 0 \}$, for any non zero $q \in Q$ (which is also the dual cone of $Q$) all separate $p$ from $Q$. There are infinitely many of these.

Comment: As I said, this was adapted from part 1 of Proposition 1 at page 6 of personal.psu.edu/vvs3/IE597/ie597_lect4.pdf . Could you please check there?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, my statement above is entirely self contained, there is nothing to check.

Comment: I am not saying anything to your answer. What I mean is, this was a question which I created from the given link and maybe I did a mistake. I did not understand the last two lines in the proof given there which I posted as this question here.

Comment: I did not understand this part in the proof given there: "Since pos W(ω) is a finitely
generated cone, there can only be finitely many such hyperplanes.
It follows that K2(ξ) can be viewed as an intersection of a finite
number of halfspaces and is therefore a convex polyhedron"

Comment: I do not understand what $K_2(\xi)$ is. The definition makes no sense to me and I do not have the energy to try and unravel it.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that as $pos W$ is a polyhedral cone, each of its (say $n$) sides is contained in a hyperplane and the those $n$ hyperplanes are enough to separate any $x\not\in pos W$ from $pos W$.

Comment: Not really. Take an example in the plane, $We_1 = e_1, W e_2 = 0$ then $(-1,0)$ is not in the positive hull but the hyperplane containing the range does not separate.